# what's the sequence of entirely positive

Tags: analysis

> **Definition 5.4.1.** Let $(a_n) _{n=1}^∞$ be a sequence of rationals. We say that
> this sequence is positively bounded away from zero iff we have a positive
> rational $c > 0$ such that $a_n ≥ c$ for all $n ≥ 1$ (***in particular, the sequence
> is entirely positive***). The sequence is negatively bounded away from zero
> iff we have a negative rational −c < 0 such that $a_n ≤ −c$ for all $n ≥ 1$
> (in particular, the sequence is entirely negative).

This definition is from Tao's book of analysis I.

What does '***in particular, the sequence is entirely positive***' mean? does it mean a sequence consisting entirely of positive numbers? Is this sequence $(0.1,0.01,0.001,...)$ entirely positive?  Thank you!

Comment: It means  that all the terms of the sequence are positive. As in, "all the elements of the sequence, in its entirety, are positive"

Comment: It means that the numbers that appear in the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ are all positive as they are all bigger than a positive rational number $c>0$.

Comment: What is the sequence " $(0.1,0.01,0.01...)$ " ? Please clarify.

Comment: sorry, it's $0.1, 0.01,0.001...$ @AdamRubinson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just a confusion of logic.

What is being said is this:

- If is a sequence is bounded away from zero, then it is entirely positive, that is, it consists of positive numbers.

The converse was not discussed in the passage, and is clearly false, as illuminaed by the example $(0.1, 0.01, 0.001,...).$